# How do I make a div shrink as the page shrink?

Tags: css

I'm working on a project where a div dynamically shrinks as the page shrinks. Unfortunately the div stays the same height this way:

**CSS**

```
.container {
  min-height: 180px;
  max-height: 350px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 350px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of fixed height, use `em`/`vh`/`%` units for height depending on what is suitable. You can also use relative height with `min-height` and `max-height` to define a range. For example, try resizing the window and see that container always occupies half of available height.

```css
.container {
  height: 50vh;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```